# How to use the VS 2019 code coverage with the Embedded debug type?

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage

I have recently learned about the Embedded debug type, which seems to be great - no longer do I need to upload PDBs to the Symbol Server during the CI build, which takes eternity when using the standard Index Sources & Publish Symbols task (for about 150+ projects it takes on average 9 minutes !!!)

However, the VS code coverage feature does not work without PDBs. So running `dotnet test --collect "Code coverage"` yields nothing if there are no PDBs.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is an open GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1748) for that, I don't think that it'll work for now

Comment: You answered it. Please, promote your comment to answer so that I could credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that there is no way to do that right now, according to open GitHub issue [1748](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1748) for adding this functionality.

You can wait until it'll be implemented or avoid using embedded PDBs for now (use `full` debug type instead)